# I am developing an iOS app for 4 inch retina , But it look distorted on 3.5 inch retina?

Tags: iphone, ios, retina-display

I am developing an iOS app for the iphone 5 (4-inch screen). It looks fine on the 4-inch retina display but when i run it on a 3.5-inch retina display, the screen appears distorted.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Put some code. if done through xib mention exactly what is getting distorted.

Comment: Please extend your question with an example of how the application is distorted. Include screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Use Autolayouts to manage it for 3.5 and 4 inches screen

Answer (score 1):

It depends for which iOS version you are developing your app. If you are developing for iOS 6 then you can use **Autolayouts**.
And if you are developing your app for lower versions the you can use **AutoResizing** feature.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make condition for in code to use it in iPhone 4 & iPhone 4S. and some place you can use auto layout of UI Components.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use different xib files for 4-inch and 3.5-inch screen.